# rsyslog prints same log twice

Tags: embedded-linux, rsyslog

I'm running an application in Debian userspace and I'm using rsyslog for logging.
I open Log in a main thread with the following command:

```
openlog(NULL, LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
```

after this the main thread creates 2 threads (detached) :

```
    pthread_create(&tx_tid, NULL,tx_main, NULL);
if(0 != th_ret_val)
{
    LOG(LEVEL_ERR,"failed to create tx thread, ret_val = %d",th_ret_val);
}
pthread_detach(tx_tid);

pthread_create(&rx_tid, NULL,rx_main, NULL);
if(0 != th_ret_val)
{
    LOG(LEVEL_ERR,"failed to create rx thread, ret_val = %d",th_ret_val);
}
pthread_detach(rx_tid);
```

and performs pthread_exit.

in the logs i see that some logs are printed twice (i know that this is the same LOG because i added a token number that is incremented on LOG and the same token number is printed) also i see that some LOGs are missing !

can someone help me explain why this happens ?

note: 
LOG macro is:

```
#define LOG(prio, ...) my_log(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, prio, __VA_ARGS__)
```

and my_log is implemented as follows:

```
#define LOG_MAX_LEN 200
```

static char full_fmt[LOG_MAX_LEN];

void my_log(const char *file, int line, const char *func, int prio, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

```
snprintf(full_fmt, LOG_MAX_LEN, "LOG:tid-%d %-30s:%003d, %-20s - %s", pthread_self(), file, line, func, fmt);
va_start(args, full_fmt);
vsyslog(prio, full_fmt, args);
//vprintf(full_fmt, args);
va_end(args);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i found out the source of the problem. i didn't protect my_log with a mutex and the message that is sent to syslog is the global string full_fmt.
adding a mutex solved this issue.